# align image to the left corner of the div vertically center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this [enter image description here][1]

[1]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZOBB.jpg), i have managed to make it work on pc but its not looking same on mobile. Here code i have managed to create so far. box height should be less than of image. i have tried `display:table` but its also not working properly. please help. thank you.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
}

.content-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #d9dde2;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #f89b0f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: #f89b0f;
}

a {
  color: #f39c12;
}

.content-header>.breadcrumb {
  background: #f89b0f;
  right: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}


.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 1200;
}

.solid-header-default {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.solid-header-success {
  background: #00a65a;

}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.gcircle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #938005;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;

}

.circle-block {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}



.circle {
  background: #938005;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;


}


.circle span {

  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.c-chart {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
}

.brandlogo-image {
  float: left;
  line-height: .8;
  margin-left: .8rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  margin-top: -6px;
  max-height: 34px;
  width: auto;
}



.dashboard-box {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: #C43805 !important;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}

.dash-img {

vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-box" >
     <img src="http://phiz.live/portal/assets/theme/img/c1.png" alt="Phiz.Live" style="margin-left:-70px;width:35%;" class="dash-img">
                                                    
                                                     
</div>
```

Comment: I think it might help if you wrap it in another wrapper flex div, with align-items: center;

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox. what ever you want to center, you it inside `.center1` and `.center2` div. For more information. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

```css
.dashboard-box {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: #C43805 !important;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}

.dash-img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.center1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  background: steelblue;
}
.center2 {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="center1" >
 <div class="center2">
  <div class="dashboard-box" >
    <img src="http://phiz.live/portal/assets/theme/img/c1.png" alt="Phiz.Live" style="margin-left:-70px;width:35%;" class="dash-img">      
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it working the way you want here: [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qnbLrf42/3/), but I changed `margin-left` to `-30px` for the image and `margin-left: 30px;`for the `.dashboard-box`. Perhaps it can help you.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">


<div class="dashboard-box" >
     <img src="http://phiz.live/portal/assets/theme/img/c1.png" alt="Phiz.Live" style="margin-left:-30px;width:35%;" class="dash-img">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.dashboard-box {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: #C43805 !important;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;

  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}
```